# Is the restriction of standard representation irreducible?

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\rho$ be the 3 dim standard representation of $S_4$.

> Is the restriction of $\rho$ to $A_4$ irreducible?

If not, then what is the explicit construction of a 3dim irreducible of $A_4$?

Comment: Both $3$-dimensional representations restrict irreducibly to $A_4$.